# Android - 'Checking/Inspecting' Android Application Code

Tags: android, portable-applications

I've tried a number of searches but can't find anything applicable, it may be because I'm just not asking the right question! So please feel free to redirect me if this has been covered elsewhere.

I'm new to Android and to development, but have an idea to use an Application to check other simple apps on the device for potential security holes (this is to design a prototype as part of a course of study).

Before I go any further, is it feasible to use an application to check through/parse/inspect the source code of another app, searching for instances of text/commands/permissions etc (similar to a grep in Linux for example)? Any starting points would be greatly appreciated, things like inter-app communication, converting code into text, searching through that text and reporting and the like.

I think the key might be using an app to inspect a Manifest file of another for permissions settings etc. I've learnt that Dalvik compiled code has big differences to the original Android 'Java'. Is it even possible to use an app to read the Manifest file of another app?

Answer (score 0):

If u use Android Studio try 'code inspect' , 'code analyze'.

Comment: Hi, thanks, I'm using Eclipse and just getting started. Is that inspecting the code within the Dev. Environment though?  What I'm thinking is more an on device package that could check newly installed apps for common problems and create a log file for reporting to an admin for example,something that could be used for BYOD solutions.

Comment: @SteveC  I think eclipse makes a background check automatically. So long you've done something wrong, you see error message and can not build.